# Mpdf not outputing several inputs with the same name in PHP

Tags: php, post, output, mpdf

I'm takes to make a simple app resume generator app ( there are a few online but they want one which we can use in case the internet "dies" ).

So far I can print out all of the data the user inputs on the page except the Education / Work experience sections where the are are several inputs with the same name, always the last one is printed when using mpdf

Thanks in advance

I have already tried to put name="example[]" but I get array:array on the output or  if i r_print it gets 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

Each `<input>` you add have the same names: `duration` and `ecole`. So, only the last one is sent when you submit your form.

You should change `duration` and `ecole`to `duration[]` and `ecole[]` so the durations and schools will be sent as arrays:

```
    txtNewInputBox.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='duration' class='schoolI' name='duration[]' placeholder='duree'> <input type='text' id='schoolName' class='schoolI' name='ecole[]' placeholder='nom ecole'> <input type='button' id='removeSchool' value='Remove Element' onclick='removeSchoolInput();'/> ";
```

Do some changes in generatecv.php to loop in theses arrays.